# Dual URL Rewrite In PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello i am newbie so sorry in advance if i am asking a question in wrong manner

I am using CodeIgniter Framework .....i am stuck in URL rewrite .......

suppose example.com is my website.....URL rewrite is working in example.com/(here URL rewrite works)

for example

```
example.com/2014_12_12--->>link to page with data
example.com/2014_12_15--->> link to page with data
(Note its done with url rewrite and it is working fine)
```

Now i want that i modify my URL with some sort of texts....like that

```
example.com/2014_12_12--->>link to -->>example.com/random text from array/2014_12_12
```

Random text that i want to put it is just for optimization/seo purposes it has no link with data

Is it possible ? I'll appreciate :-)

Sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make below changes in application/config.php file

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
   ```
2. Make .htacces file in your root directory using below code

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

Comment: can you please explain functionality of $1, robots\.txt